# Event Pattern Detection with Reaction/ECA rules on Stream of Events using AND, OR and SEQ

Tags: java, events, event-driven, complex-event-processing, snoop

I have a event stream where events are a set of attribute/value-pairs, like:
`E1 = {(ID, val), (attr, val), (attr, val), ... }`

I want to detect simple patters using only SNOOP style event algebra, namely `AND, OR, SEQ`, no parentheses.
Example: `E1 AND E2 OR E4` , where `E` is an identifier.

Now, I want to use some *Event Processing Engine* to track the event stream and react, in case a pattern is found. The rules are similar to [RuleML ECA](http://ruleml.org/reaction/0.2/syntax.htm) rule as in this example:

```
<rule style="active" ...>
   <on> e.g. E1 SEQ/AND/OR ... </on>
   <do> alert </do>
</rule>
```

These rules ought to be generated/parsed from a list. 
It would be awesome, if anybody could recommend me a CEP engine that is able to detect simple patterns as stated above.
 I've tried [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/) and prova (Prolog + Java), but could not manage to "parse" the patterns from a list into a set of rules.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Does anyone know, if Drools might do the trick? Especially, I need to be able to use `AND,OR,SEQ` within the on/when-part of a rule.